# Как сделать красивый input type='file' через css и js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

Как сделать красивый input `type='file'` через css и js? Как сделать чтобы при клике button выполняется input?

```css
button {
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload">
  <button>Upload</button>
  <input type="file" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непосредственно `input` изменить не получится, но можно его убрать и работать с ним опосредованно.

Можно подсмотреть на [jQuery-File-Upload demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html)

Делаем кнопку, внутрь вставляем название кнопки и `input`.

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <span>Select files...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" name="files[]" multiple="" type="file">
</span>
```

Прячем и предусмотрительно увеличиваем `input`:

```
.fileinput-button input {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    direction: ltr;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Теперь он невидим и занимает все пространство кнопки. [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwEEQo)

Второй способ:

```
<input type="file" id='upload' />
<label for="upload" class="button">Upload</label>
```

css:

```
#upload{
  display: none;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZOOJZ)

Теперь можно настраивать внешний вид кнопки произвольным образом.